# Limit QML PathView to 1 index swipe

Tags: qt, view, indexing, qml

I have created a sort of page switcher using pathview element which works fine but if you flick hard enough it flicks over a few pages. I want to know if there is a way I can limit my pathview element to only be able to change 1 index at a time?

**Edit:**
I don't want to know how I can create my own switcher thing, I already have the pathview one working smooth with the pages following my finger etc. all I want to know is how I can limit pathview to changing only 1 index at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Qt 5 has this functionality so I will just leave it like this until then.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `MouseArea` and `incrementCurrentIndex`/`decrementCurrentIndex`

```
Rectangle {
    // ...
    PathView {
        id: path_view
        anchors.fill: parent
        interactive: false
        // model, delegate, etc...
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            property int x_pos
            onPressed: {
                x_pos = mouse.x
            }
            onReleased: {
                if (x_pos > mouse.x) {
                    path_view.incrementCurrentIndex()
                }
                else {
                    path_view.decrementCurrentIndex()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I want something smooth, I want the pages to flick normally.

Comment: What do you mean by 'smooth' and 'normally'? Have you tried this?

Comment: I believe there is no way to have tight control over `PathView`. You have to roll your own.